# MongoDB instance vs relationship denormalistion

Tags: mongodb

I playing with the best way to model mongodb documents

I am modelling a school.

A Student has many subjects.

```
Student{
  subjects:[ {name:'',
              level:'',
              short name:''
             },
             {...},
             {...}]
}
```

Decided to denormalise and embed subjects into students for performance.

There are rare cases where a subject needs to be queried and updated.

```
subjects.all
subject1.short_name = 'something new'
```

I know I will have to iterate through every student to update every subject reocrd.

However whast the best way to return all unique subjects?

Can you do a unique search of student.subjects names for example?

Or is it better to have another collection which is

```
Subjects{
    name:'',
    level:'',
    short name:''
}
```

I still keep the denormalised Student.subject. But this is simply there for quering all the subjects on offer.

An updated would update this + every embeded Student.subject?

Any suggestions/recommendations?

Comment: you can't query for everything in a denormalised db with great proficiency. Your data structure should depend on what queries are important for you. First make a list of all queries you need and add those here. A many-to-many relationship like this usually requires normalised structure but you can duplicate data at a few places to make querying easier.

Comment: @Jayz Data duplication is the bane of database programming, you would definitely not want to duplicate this

Comment: @Sammaye, agree with your generic statement but applies only to relational dbs. It is unavoidable in certain cases with non-relational dbs else some queries may take too long to execute.

Comment: @Jayz Indeed I do agree with that, however I would cover it to include all databases, for example, facebook regularly denormalises wall post data to prevent having to join in MySQL, duplicating certain values over and then caching the row in a further cache layer.

Answer (score 0):

> However whast the best way to return all unique subjects?

This is a short fall of your schema here. You traded the ability to do this kind of thing easily in return for other speed benefits that you would do more often.

Currently the only real way is to either use the `distinct()` command ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/ ):

```
db.students.distinct('subjects.name');
```

or the aggregation framework:

```
db.students.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$subjects'},
    {$group:{_id:'$subjects.name'}}
])
```

Like so.

As for schema recommendation, if you intend to make this kind of query often then I would factor out subjects into a separate collection.